# Magento2 after installation error (Exception log)

Tags: magento2, installation, php-7

I have installed Magento 2 and after first exception, I get an error as below.

```
[2019-05-16 08:16:50] main.CRITICAL: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magento2.core_config_data' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `core_config_data` AS `main_table` {"exception":"[object] (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception(code: 42): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magento2.core_config_data' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `core_config_data` AS `main_table` at /var/www/vhosts/magento2/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:235, PDOException(code: 42S02): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magento2.core_config_data' doesn't exist at /var/www/vhosts/magento2/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228)"} []
```

what does it mean?

and how to fix it?

Help me. Thanks In advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check prefix in the database.

Or upgrade the setup version : `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Comment: Thanks for answer

Comment: Can add exact command

Answer (score 1):

Seems like installation not good, try to drop db and again install it

And install magento using ssh

```
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://127.0.0.1/magento2/ --db-host=localhost --db-name=magento --db-user=magento --db-password=magento --admin-firstname=Magento --admin-lastname=User --admin-email=user@example.com --admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --language=en_US --currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1
```

Comment: do I need to write full line in terminal?

can u give me example of this.
I am not aware of ssh